# How to add the UserId to posted data by Logged User in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So what I'm doing might seem simple, but I don't know exactly how to do it.

I have already registered and logged in with an account (I'm using the default membership system used in ASP.NET MVC 4) and so I want to do add my UserId to some data I'm inserting to the database.

This is the model of the data I'm inserting:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Reroute.Models
{
    public class Request
    {
        public int      RequestId { get; set; }
        // I want to add UserId based on my current session
        public int      UserId { get; set; }
        public string   OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string   TrackingNumber { get; set; }
        public string   CurrentAddress { get; set; }
        public string   NewAddress { get; set; }
        public string   Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the ActionResult (here's where I supposed I have to make the changes):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Request collection)
{
    try
    {
        _db.Requests.Add(collection);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Content("Done! Added to DB");
     }
     catch
     {
        return View();
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: What mechanism do you have for the login? Are you using the `FormsAuthentication` class?

Comment: what problem/obstacle are you facing?

Comment: @vonv. Yes, FormsAuthentication

Comment: @DaveA : the problem is, that I'm somewhat confused about how to add new stuff to the model (in this case, I need to add the UserId).

Comment: Do you mean how to add fields to model (not likely since you seem capable of implementing a model) or how to populate you `UserId` from the view to controller

Comment: @DaveA When I post the data in the DB everything is saved but not my `UserId`, I want to know how to add it to the DB with all the other information.

Comment: Add your controller code with ORM to your Question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27447/discussion-between-danny-and-dave-a)

Comment: So have you saved the UsedId somewhere or is that part of the question?

Comment: @vonv. it's part of the question; how I grab the `UserId` of my session, and include it in the data that is being saved into the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this it gets u the userid ...

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the UserId of the authenticated user in Session after logging in:

```
Session["UserId"] = userId;
```

or since you are using FormsAuthentication you can either use the UserData property as [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx) or do a nice-that-will-do-trick:

```
public SignInUser(string name, string id) {
    // store the userid
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(name + '|' + id, false);
}
```

then retrieve the Name and UserId like this:

```
public int CurrentUserId
{
    get
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null) return 0;

        return context.Request.IsAuthenticated
                    ? Convert.ToInt32(context.User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[1])
                    : 0;
    }
}

public string CurrentUserName
{
    get
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context == null) return string.Empty;

        return context.Request.IsAuthenticated 
            ? context.User.Identity.Name.Split('|')[0] 
            : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

You can have those method and properties in a class so you have them in one place, I actually do it that way. Now, you can call it in your controller like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Request collection)
{
    try
    {
        collection.UserId = _authProvider.CurrentUserId;
        // if you want to use session, I prefer the FormsAuthentication approach
        // you need to do additional check that the Session has not expired (not null)
        collection.UserId = Session["UserId"];

        _db.Requests.Add(collection);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Content("Done! Added to DB");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

`_authProvider` is an instance of the class that has the code I gave above.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var loggedInUserName=Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
var user=Membership.GetUser(loggedInUserName);
var key = user.ProviderUserKey;
```

T

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Create` also has a `GET` which is loaded up and used as the model for `Create.cshtml`, you would just need to set it explicitly in that `ActionResult`

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{
   Result model = new Result();
   model.UserId = myUserId;
}
```

Then in your `Create.cshtml` you could have a hidden field for it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
```

I would still check in the `POST` to make sure the user doing the saving is allowed to be saving and hasn't spoofed your hidden field value to somebody completely different.